# React - Event bubbling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react. I am not quite how should I write a event handling so when I click on `a`, I can alert data-href. Right now if I click on div or img, it will trigger an event, but since the target is actually not `a` it will alert null, which is not what I want.

```
test(e){alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-href'))}
<div>
  <ui>
    <li >
      <a data-href = 'http://cnn.com'  onClick = {e = > this.test(e)>
          <div>
            <img src = 'someimage.jpg'}>
            hi there
          </div>
      </a>
    <li>
  </ui>
</div>
```

edit:

Something like this
conversationList() & selectConversation() is what I am talking about here~

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import * as actions from './actions/index';

import io from 'socket.io-client';


class Chat extends React.Component{ 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {recipientId: '', messageBuffer:'asdfadsfasdf'};
        this.userList = this.userList.bind(this);
        this.changeRecipient = this.changeRecipient.bind(this);
        this.insertText = this.insertText.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.loadConversationsSocket();
        this.props.loadConversations();
        this.props.loadRecipients();
    }



    participantsNames(participants){
        console.log('in par ');
        console.log(participants);  
        return participants.map(participant => (<div key= {participant._id}>{participant.name}</div>));
    }

    selectConversation(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.tagName);
        let data = this.getAttribute('data-href');
        alert(data);
    }

    conversationList(){
        if(!(this.props.conversations.length === 0)){
            console.log('in conversation if');


            return this.props.conversations.map(conversation =>(<li key = {conversation.conversation._id} >
                <a data-href = {'http://localhost:8000/messaages/'+conversation.conversation._id} onClick = {(e)=>this.selectConversation(e)}>
                    <div>
                        participants: {this.participantsNames(conversation.conversation.participants)}
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        {conversation.message[0].auther}
                        {conversation.message[0].body}
                    </div>
                </a>

            </li>))
        }
    }



    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.conversationList()}
                </ul>
            </div>)
    }


}

function mapStateToProps(state) {  
    return { recipients: state.recipients, conversations: state.conversations};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Chat);
```

Comment: I don't really see any react code here, can you paste your entire component ?

Comment: @klugjo I added the component(with some editing so the code might not wotk as a whole)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onClick` handler is attached to the `img`, not to `a`. This is the first  problem.

Then you should update your code to query `event.currentTarget`.

> **`event.currentTarget`** - identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses
>   the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler
>   has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the
>   element on which the event occurred.

You should write your event handler like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

  test(e){
   alert(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-href'))
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <a onClick={this.test} data-href="foo">
            <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" />
            <div>clickMe</div>
          </a>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would suggest also reading [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) about handling events.

Comment: But I do want to have a <div> and <img> child node under <a>.

Comment: @I-PINGOu, ok, so what should happen when you click on them?

Comment: I want to alert data-href in <a> whether I click on <img> or <div> under <a> or <a> itself.

Comment: Dan Cantir I just realized I put onClick in img tag. I meant to put it in <a> tag.

Comment: Thank you. I know this is a work around. But I think what I essentially want to know is how to get the element with the onclick funciton. Right now it works because we know the parent is the noe with onclick function. But what if it's more nested. Is there a way to get the element with onclick without knowing it's relation with the target? Thank you

Comment: Maybe currentTarget?

Comment: @I-PINGOu, yep, just tested and it works, you answered the your own question! :)